# Sed command to replace comma-separated values with pipe-separated values

Tags: shell, unix, sed, gawk

My CSV file has records in the following format:

```
571283,1,"R","01/15/2002","IBMS,SL"
```

I want to convert them to the following format:

```
571283|1|R|01/15/2002|IBMS,SL
```

I tried this:

```
sed -e 's/ //g' -e 's/\"\,\"/\|/g' -e 's/\,\"/\|/g' -e 's/\"$//' test.csv
```

but the output I am getting is:

```
571283,1|R|01/15/2002|IBMS,SL
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 4):

Using `gnu-awk` with `FPAT`:

```
awk -v FPAT='"[^"]+"|[^,]+' -v OFS='|' '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) gsub(/"/, "", $i)} 1' file

571283|1|R|01/15/2002|IBMS,SL
```

In case `gnu-awk` is unavailable use this `perl` command:

```
perl -pe 's/(?=(([^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$),/|/g; s/"//g' file

571283|1|R|01/15/2002|IBMS,SL
```

Comment: No,output what I am getting is 571283,1,R,01/15/2002,IBMS,SL

Comment: As I wrote this requires **gnu awk**. What is your awk version?

Comment: Also check my `perl` alternative.

Comment: Thanks Anubhava,I tried with perl it does work.have one more requirement pls help me on this
everyday I am Receiving CSV file in my mail server.file has field like transaction amount value(6000000)since field format is in general mode I am seeing value like 6000000 but when I change it to number I see 6000000.01 Now problem is I have to place this file in unix server for further processing. When I do so and cat my csv file in unix server I get value for this field is 6000000.01 but I don't want .01 in my csv file it should be 6000000 which I can see in my csv file before placing to unix server

Comment: If that is happening inside your `perl` command you need to fix that. In any case that `.01` thing is not related to the problem asked in question. I would suggest you post a new question for this and mark this answer accepted. We keep one problem per thread and adding new problems via comments is not good for future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
sed -e 's/,/|/' -e 's/\"\,\"/\|/g' -e 's/\,\"/\|/g' -e 's/\"$//' test.csv
```

Result is:

```
571283|1|R|01/15/2002|IBMS,SL
```

Your first sequence:

```
-e 's/ //g'
```

has to be changed in:

```
-e 's/,/|/'
```

Expanding to reply to your comment.

First of all you have to take care of the fact that sed is sequential, so the order of the transformations is important.

In your string:

```
Market Basket - WF Note A-2,RECM-PS Transfer,09/22/2015,"330930929, 330931800",,
```

You have same characters that you want to transform in different ways. The use of g for global and the sequence of transformations are therefore very important.

Let us build the sequence:

first of all let us get rid of ",, that we want to transform in ||:

```
sed -e 's/\"\,\,/||/' test.csv
```

will give us:

```
Market Basket - WF Note A-2,RECM-PS Transfer,09/22/2015,"330930929, 330931800||
```

Then we do the same with ," that we want to become |:

```
sed -e 's/\"\,\,/||/' -e 's/\,\"/|/' test.csv
```

gives:

```
Market Basket - WF Note A-2,RECM-PS Transfer,09/22/2015|330930929, 330931800||
```

Now we still have 2 commas we want to transform in | but not the third, the simply way is to repeat twice that transformation:

```
sed -e 's/\"\,\,/||/' -e 's/\,\"/|/' -e 's/,/|/' -e 's/,/|/' test.csv
```

Market Basket - WF Note A-2|RECM-PS Transfer|09/22/2015|330930929, 330931800||

That is!

Advise:

1. Think to your sequence of transformations strategy;
2. Apply one transformation at the time and look at the result, remembering that that will be fed to the next one.

But finally I think you need to transform BOTH strings at the same time, so that:

```
Market Basket - WF Note A-2,RECM-PS Transfer,09/22/2015,"330930929, 330931800",,
571283,1,"R","01/15/2002","IBMS,SL"
```

becomes:

```
Market Basket - WF Note A-2|RECM-PS Transfer|09/22/2015|330930929, 330931800||
571283|1|R|01/15/2002|IBMS,SL
```

This is the sequence of transformations that does that:

```
sed  -e 's/\",\"/|/' -e 's/\"\,\,/||/' -e 's/\,\"/|/' -e 's/,/|/' -e 's/,/|/' -e 's/\"//g' test.csv
```

Regards

Comment: Thanks,it work for above scenario but i  have few Records like this also in my file.puting one sample Record.

Market Basket - WF Note A-2,RECM-PS Transfer,09/22/2015,"330930929, 330931800",,

sed -e 's/,/|/' -e 's/\"\,\"/\|/g' -e 's/\,\"/\|/g' -e 's/\"$//' test.csv

output i am getting is below.it replace one first occurence of , with | also it not replacing ", with |

Market Basket - WF Note A-2|RECM-PS Transfer,09/22/2015|330930929, 330931800",,

Desired output what i want is.

Market Basket - WF Note A-2|RECM-PS Transfer|09/22/2015|330930929, 330931800||

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e 's/ //g' -e 's/\"\,\"/\|/g' -e 's/\,\"/\|/g' -e 's/\"$//' -e 's/\,/\|/g' btest.txt
```

Comment: Indeed text transformations are similar to what in mathematics is called a non commutative group. Rotations are a non commutative group. This means that the order of the transformations is important. You have multiple ways to obtain the same result. Text transformation are not exactly a non commutative group, as not always you have inverse operation: when you transform a sequence of characters already present in the text you cannot go back applying the inverse operation.

Comment: Thanks it works.have one more requirement pls help me on this.everyday I am Receiving CSV file in my mail server.file has field like transaction amount value(6000000)since field format is in general mode I am seeing value like 6000000 but when I change it to number I see 6000000.01 Now problem is I have to place this file in unix server for further processing. When I do so and cat my csv file in unix server I get value for this field is 6000000.01 but I don't want .01 in my csv file it should be 6000000 which I can see in my csv file before placing to unix server.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, **using a bona fide CSV parser is the simplest and most robust choice** when it comes to parsing CSV data.

For instance, `python`'s CSV parsing provides a straightforward solution:

```
$ python -c 'import csv,sys; reader=csv.reader(sys.stdin)
for row in reader:
  print("|".join(row))' < test.csv
571283|1|R|01/15/2002|IBMS,SL
```

As a one-liner (in `bash`, `ksh`, or `zsh`):

```
python -c $'import csv,sys; reader=csv.reader(sys.stdin)\nfor row in reader:\n  print("|".join(row))' < test.csv
```